# flutter socket.io-client not disconnect

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client in flutter app. But when user logout I want to disconnect from server but it didn't happen.

```dart
class WebsocketService {
  // final Socket? socket;
  IO.Socket? chatSocket;

  WebsocketService()
      : chatSocket =
            IO.io("$Server/${SocketConstants.ChatNameSpace}", <String, dynamic>{
          'transports': <String>['websocket'],
          'query': <String, dynamic>{
            "access_token": token,
          }
        });

  void logout() {
    debugPrint("will logout socket");
    chatSocket?.clearListeners();
    chatSocket?.destroy();
    chatSocket?.dispose();
    chatSocket!.disconnect();
    chatSocket?.io.disconnect();
    chatSocket!.io.close();
    chatSocket!.io.destroy(chatSocket);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While initializing socket please add enableForceNew() function.